# How to get protractor instance number when doing parallel tests

Tags: protractor

When I'm running my tests in parallel, for example using the config below I would like to access the running instance number inside my test (for example 'instance#1', 'instance#2'..., 'instance#5'). Is it possible?

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  shardTestFiles: true,
  maxInstances: 5
}
```

Comment: If you consider adding gulp or grunt to do your parallel tests you can pass a params.session as a variable and also control the order of test execution.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for constructing the log header which has the instance is here - [taskLogger.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/30102fbdaa6354e8ba1a067c6731799aa0f0ff42/lib/taskLogger.ts#L62) This might be of interest to you.

The below instance we see is constructed from the below code snippet which is a amalgamation of the capabilities we provide and the #taskID generated.

```
[chrome #01-0]
```

So there is not a single parameter which is fetch your instance but a re-construction of below code from your test

`public log(data: string): void {
    var tag = '[';
    var capabilities = this.task.capabilities;
    tag += (capabilities.logName) ?
        capabilities.logName :
        (capabilities.browserName) ? capabilities.browserName : '';
    tag += (capabilities.version) ? (' ' + capabilities.version) : '';
    tag += (capabilities.platform) ? (' ' + capabilities.platform) : '';
    tag += (capabilities.logName && capabilities.count < 2) ?
        '' :
        ' #' + this.task.taskId;
    tag += '] ';`

Answer (score -2):

You might try `logName` from `getProcessedConfig`

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(config=> console.log(config.logName));
```

Comment: It returns undefined. Do I need some kind of special config for that?

Comment: Try 'console.log(config)' first, to see whole structure of object, there might be something useful

Comment: logName is not returned in Capabilities object by default. Its only returned when we provided logName in the config.js - capabilities and will not server our purpose